# How can I stop the execution of a Python function from outside of it?

Tags: python, function, exit

So I have this library that I use and within one of my functions I call a function from that library, which happens to take a really long time. Now, at the same time I have another thread running where I check for different conditions, what I want is that if a condition is met, I want to cancel the execution of the library function.

Right now I'm checking the conditions at the start of the function, but if the conditions happen to change while the library function is running, I don't need its results, and want to return from it.

Basically this is what I have now.

```
def my_function():
    if condition_checker.condition_met():
        return
    library.long_running_function()
```

Is there a way to run the condition check every second or so and return from my_function when the condition is met?

I've thought about decorators, coroutines, I'm using 2.7 but if this can only be done in 3.x I'd consider switching, it's just that I can't figure out how.

Comment: The only thing I can think to do is put in occasional checks to see if the condition is met in the long running function. If it's a loop of some sort that would be easy to break out but I'm certain there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot terminate a thread. Either the library supports cancellation by design, where it internally would have to check for a condition every once in a while to abort if requested, or you have to wait for it to finish.

What you can do is call the library in a subprocess rather than a thread, since processes can be terminated through signals. Python's [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module provides a threading-like API for spawning forks and handling IPC, including synchronization.

Or spawn a separate subprocess via [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) if forking is too heavy on your resources (e.g. memory footprint through copying of the parent process).

I can't think of any other way, unfortunately.

Comment: So in my_function I'd start a subprocess with the library function and then wait for either the condition in the condition checker to be met (and then stop the library function) or for the long running function to finish before I return from my function. I think this would work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I think you want to run your `long_running_function` in a separate thread, and have it occasionally report its information to the main thread.

[This post](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) gives a similar example within a wxpython program.

Presuming you are doing this outside of wxpython, you should be able to replace the wx.CallAfter and wx.Publisher with [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [PubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/).

It would look something like this:

```py
import threading
import time

def myfunction():
    # subscribe to the long_running_function
    while True:
        # subscribe to the long_running_function and get the published data
        if condition_met:
            # publish a stop command
            break
        time.sleep(1)

def long_running_function():
    for loop in loops:
        # subscribe to main thread and check for stop command, if so, break
        # do an iteration
        # publish some data

threading.Thread(group=None, target=long_running_function, args=())  # launches your long_running_function but doesn't block flow
myfunction()
```

I haven't used pubsub a ton so I can't quickly whip up the code but it should get you there.

As an alternative, do you know the stop criteria before you launch the `long_running_function`? If so, you can just pass it as an argument and check whether it is met internally.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the long_running function, well in this case I think I might, but I wanted a more general solution that didn't involve altering libraries.