# Get process Id of a function, not process of what is running my Django server

Tags: python, django, process

I am currently using psutil to do...

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.kill()
```

...In an attempt to kill the process of one function (that I thought I was getting the pid of with):

```
os.getpid()
```

...Though this kills my entire manage.py runserver command and I have to restart the server.

Does anyone know what I can do here?

Answer (score 1):

Functions do not have a process ID independent of the VM. Your question is meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps my last sentence can negate your last sentence if you actually understand what I am trying to do

Comment: There is no such thing as "the process of one function". All functions run in the same process.

Comment: What, then, is the purpose of the multiprocessing package that I've just found? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: It's certainly not to make any arbitrary Python program use multiple processes...

Comment: For future readers, this is the question I am asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906558/how-can-i-stop-the-execution-of-a-python-function-from-outside-of-it

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr - Did you read the answer to that question? " call the library "... it doesn't say anything about terminating a function.

Comment: I've answered my question. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio said, my question didn't make sense: "Functions do not have a process ID independent of the VM"

Though to answer the essence of my question: "how can i stop the execution of a function (infinite while loop) from outside of that function?"

We check a flag, e.g. a value set in a database. Helped by a kind stranger in #python in freenode